# Non existing pages does not return 404

Tags: 7, debugging

I have a strange problem when i visit some page like this

> example.com/node/386 "onmouseover=prompt(9999) "

**from Drupal perspective that page doesn't exists right ?**

getting something like this

[image]

Comment: The second portion of the url is parsed as Javascript in your example. I could however not reproduce this on any other Drupal site. So I guess it is not Drupal related, but a browser or module setting somehow.

Comment: @Neograph734, yes it is not happening on my other sites as well, can you guess the reason?

Comment: Could be anything, browser, server, module... If you have the same browser and server, you could try by disabling modules one by one. But I don't know if you will find it then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was alterting the body class array for some reason with a non safe code.

```
$variables['classes_array'][] = 'mysite-'.arg(0);
```

Now, changed to

```
$variables['classes_array'][] = 'mysite-'.check_plain(arg(0));
```

As you can see javascript gets executed as added it to dom `body`

[check_plain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7)

> Encodes special characters in a plain-text string for display as HTML.

PHP [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will work too.

> (PHP 4, PHP 5) strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

Hope someone finds it helpful.